# libreoffice5.1.3 error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-glib-1.so.2

Tags: centos, libreoffice

I installed libreoffice5.1.3 on my VPS centos 7

when i try to launch libreoffice it is showing following error

libreoffice5.3 javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment! Warning: failed to read path from javaldx /opt/libreoffice5.3/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file

How can i resolve it

Thank you in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for programming questions. I think you would have better luck in the CentOS forums: https://www.centos.org/forums/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is later but try to install this package:

```
yum install libdbus-glib-1.so.2
```

So after require this packages:

```
libdbus-glib-1.so.2
libcairo.so.2
libcups.so.2libSM.so.6
```

If it is, install all